# Objective-C NSData convert to MemoryStream

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert `NSData` to `MemoryStream`.

**Example:**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MRZ" ofType:@"cls"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];
```

How do I convert fileData  to `MemoryStream`?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `MemoryStream`? You mean with `NSStream` and `NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey`? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html ?

Comment: android sample:

 fileName = "LoadData_DocOCR/Dictionary/MRZNationality.txt";
    asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, fileName.c_str(), AASSET_MODE_STREAMING);
    size = AAsset_getLength(asset);

    if(asset == NULL) LOGE("asset is NULL");

    MemoryStream streamNationality(size);
    while ((nb_read = AAsset_read(asset, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) {
        streamNationality.Write(buf, 0, nb_read);
    }
    streamNationality.Seek(0);
    AAsset_close(asset);

I need objective-c version.
thanks.